# How uWSGI invokes a WSGI application

Tags: python, wsgi, uwsgi

[PEP 3333](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/#the-server-gateway-side) states:

> The server or gateway invokes the application callable once for each
>   request it receives from an HTTP client, that is directed at the
>   application.

Then there follows an example how a CGi script invokes a WSGI application callable.

But how [uWSGI](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/), being a binary application, invokes a WSGI callable written in Python?

Does it have its own Python wrapper which connects to a socket and then calls the application callable?

Or uses some kind of sub-interpreter magic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uWSGI links with libpython, so it is effectively a full python interpreter. It loads the code on startup and then wait for requests. At every request it runs the specified callable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I guess you are the author of uWSGI? So it calls the application callable as a C library call?

Comment: Yes, after having parsed the request and built the python dictionary it invokes the callable using the PyEval_CallObject function exposed by libpython